# str.toString() returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript

When i do `str.replace(/\n/g, '')`

I'm getting the error, that replace is not a function.

When i do `str.toString()` it returns  `[object Object]`

is my String being treated like a JSON object or what?
my string is a website body.

the string is assigned by making a GET request to a URL.

Comment: Why did i get downvoted..?

Comment: How exactly does `str` get its value?

Comment: `str.replace('/\n/g, '')` is not correct tho, should be `str.replace(/\n/g, '')`

Comment: Also you are not saving `str` variable after replacing it. You should save it `str = str.replace()`

Comment: I know all this, it was just a writed version of my code.

Comment: "_Why did i get downvoted..?_" Because your question is not complete. You don't show how `str` is assigned, so we can't really see what you are actually doing wrong here.

Comment: @BobJensen you know all these above but saying **my string is a website body.** You gotta be kiddin

Comment: Why do a gotta be kiddin..?

Comment: What do you mean by **my string is a website body**? It does not mean anything to anyone here.

Comment: `str` is probably not a string. It is most likely an object. What does `typeof str` return? Add how str is initialized.

Comment: Could you add your `str` assignment to your question?

Comment: typeof str returns 'object', ok, so now i know why it isnt working, but it weird because its just a website's page source.

Comment: @BobJensen There were about 4 people asking you how `str` is assigned exactly for this. Mind adding it?

Answer (score 1):

`str.toString()` returns `[object Object]` because your `str` variable is an object

```
str = {};
str.toString();
```

> `$ "[object Object]"`

Try to debug your var with a console function `console.log(str)`, this will probably return the entire object tree.

---

If you are looking for HTML content you can use the `innerHTML` attribute as below: -

`str.innerHTML`

Comment: innerHTML isn't a function; rather an attribute. Remove innerHTML() and replace it with innerHTML with no brackets

Answer (score 0):

That's because `str` variable contains Object instead of String. You can make `console.log(str)` to see what value does it have.

Comment: str is a website body.

Comment: @BobJensen it is an object. What this var should contain? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: to check if it contains a substring

Comment: @BobJensen if you want to get all text from your page your `str` assignment should be this: `const str = document.body.innerText;`

Answer (score 0):

You stated that `str` was the "website body". I am assuming what you did wrong is you probably wrote

```
var str = document.body; // Returns Node
```

instead of

```
var str = document.body.innerHTML; // Returns String
```

The reason is that `[object Object]` is the string version of a JSON object (or a Node):

```js
var str = {};
console.log(str.toString());
```